# Microsoft toucless sdk demo

Tags: sdk

What type of markers are to be used in microsoft touchless SDK I tried few thigs like cap of bottle. but I am not able to work with any demo give in touchless.. So suggest me what to do..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need good light and high contrast between the colors of the marker and your background on the touchless SDK. The SDK was rather rudimentary more proof of concept than actual product. Now that the Kinect SDK is released, you might want to consider using that instead.

Comment: I dont have kincet device with me so I think I cant go for that... but its a good idea...